# OData Get method returns Complex Type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm just getting started with OData using Asp.Net Web API.

I declare in WebApiConfig.cs

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Staff>("staffs");

return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

In StaffsController.cs

```
public class StaffsController : ODataController
{
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public StaffsController()
    {
        this.unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var q = this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data.Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Id, p.Ext });
        // Or Grouping here to return a Complex Type                   
        return Ok(q);
    }
}
```

It return 406 error, but if I change

```
var q = this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data.Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Id, p.Ext });
// Or Grouping here to return a Complex Type
```

to

```
var q = this.unitOfWork.StaffRepository.Data;
```

It works.

I've search on Google for a while but still found nothing. Could you help me out if we can do that or we have other ways to reach that?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking here. What exactly is the problem? What are you trying to achieve that isn't working? Is there an error that is occurring?

Comment: Hi @TomDoesCode, you see Get method have select anonymous type? If it returns ...Data; it's fine. But if return select { }, it return 406 error.
I edited the question, could you take a look?

Comment: Why do you need to use the `Select`? What is wrong with just returning the `Data` property?

Comment: I want get Staff information list with some statistic data like how much asset staff has and is able to filtering on client side using ajax and paging data

Answer (score 0):

The type that you pass into the generic parameter for `builder.EntitySet` - in your case `Staff` - needs to match the object that you return from the `Get` method. Because you used `Staff`, the variable `q` needs to be of type `IQueryable<Staff>`.

The `Data` property is of this type so it works, but the anonymous type for the version that isn't working obviously isn't so it doesn't work.

Following on from your comment

> I want get Staff information list with some statistic data

In order to add different properties to the response, you need to create a new object type that you pass into the `builder.EntitySet` generic parameter and then create it in `Select` statement in the controller.

However, what you are doing in the example, seems to be just returning properties that are already on the `Staff` object. You could use an OData `$select` statement to do this. For example:

```
http://yoururl/staffs?$select=Name,Id,Ext
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, On Asp.Net site, it says OData supports open data type but it requires data has form. It means we must have data with format in structure we want, it doesn't provide a IQueryable from SQL statement has complex type. You know what I mean?

Comment: Yes. I agree Tom's example, that you should use $select to return the certain properties, other that to create a anonymous type to let ODL serialize. 
Besides, OData do supports open data type. Open type is the type in which it can include both declared properties and dynamic properties.

Comment: @TaiPhatLam If you add a `DynamicRouteConstraint` to `config.Routes` in `WebApi.cs` then that takes a `Func<HttpRequestMessage, IEdmModel>` parameter which you can use to generate the model for each request.